# How to add toolTip for objects in QTextBrowser?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt4

I'm adding some paragraphs in QTextBrowser and want to add toolTip for them. I tried using hover but QTextBrower doesn't support hover I think.

I'm able to call a function on clicking though.

EDIT:seperate toolTip for each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you're adding the paragraphs, but if you're using markup the solution is simple: just use the `title` attribute.

```
    <p title="tootip">some block of text</p>
```

However, if the paragraphs are being added programmatically, you can use `QTextCharFormat`, which has a [setToolTip](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextcharformat.html#setToolTip) method.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this?

```
b=QTextBrowser()
b.setToolTip('Simple text browser')
```

It works for TextFields

Comment: This would add a toolTip for the whole textBrowser. I want to add seperate tooltips for each object/paragraph in the textBrowser

Comment: @RomilAggarwal i gave answer before you edited the question and look now iam getting downvotes because you changed the question, thanks.